# Нажать на все кнопки по очереди

Tags: javascript

Есть:

```
setInterval (
    function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('farm_icon_a').click();
    }, 1000
);
```

Получаю:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function
>       at :3:56

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('farm_icon_a')` дает вам массив всех элементов, пробегаетесь по массиву и делаете на каждом из них клик.

Comment: 1. Получайте елемент, а не массив. 2. Проверяйте есть ли у елемента click  `if (item.click) item.click()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать `querySelector` вместо `getElementsByClassName`, потому, что он кэширует результат.
getElementsByClassName возвращает nodeList, который является псевдомассивом у которого нет методов обычных массивов.
Вам необходимо nodeList преобразовать в массив через `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)` или `Array.from()` (это новый метод и не во всех браузерах поддерживается), пройтись по этому массиву циклом и на каждый элемент сделать `click()`

```
var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.farm_icon_a'));

buttons.forEach(function(button, index) {
  setTimeout(function() { button.click(); }, index * 100); 
});
```

Comment: Отлично! А не подскажете как сделать задержку на нажатия следующей кнопки?

Comment: Кстати, мне нужно что бы скрипт повторно запускался

Comment: ну в forEach есть 2 параметр index, который отвечает за index.
Вы можете использовать это, чтоб создавать на каждую итерацию новый промежуток времени.
`buttons.forEach((button,index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
 button.click();
}, 100 * index);
});`
Тогда каждый след. элемент будет запускаться с задержкой + 100 мс.
А как запускать повторно код, это уже вам решать. Можете использовать setInterval, а можете по клику.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const: http://ssmaker.ru/16a60f68.png

Comment: const и тому подобное, это es5 синтаксис, который старые браузеры не поддерживают. Замените его на var, я исправил свой ответ.

Comment: Проблема именно в setInterval, без setInterval - работает

Comment: На скриншоте, вы не обернули код функцией и не выставили время.

Comment: @РодионПоляков если ваша задача по очереди кликать на что-то, то использования setTimeout должно хватить, оборачивать это в setInterval нет необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval (
    function() {
        var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('farm_icon_a');
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
           arr[i].click();
        }

    }, 1000
);
```

Comment: Вы повторили ошибку автора. у nodeList нет forEach.

Comment: @DimenSi я эту сотону сейчас затестил, я столько вкладок в жизни не видел)

Answer (score 0):

```
// get button array (Из соседнего ответа)
var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.farm_icon_a'));

var clickers = buttons.map(function(button) { 
  return function(){
    button.click();
  }
});


var index = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  if (index == clickers.length) index = 0;
  clickers[index]();
  index++;
}, 500);
```